# Can reflection be used to instantiate an objects base class properties?

Tags: c#, reflection, inheritance, jira, copy-constructor

Like this:

```
    public class remoteStatusCounts : RemoteStatus 
{
    public int statusCount;

    public remoteStatusCounts(RemoteStatus r)
    {
        Type t = r.GetType();
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in t.GetProperties())
        {
            this.property(p) = p.GetValue(); //example pseudocode
        }
    }
}
```

The example is a bit simple (it's from the Jira API - RemoteStatus has 4 properties), but imagine the base class had 30 properties. I don't want to manually set all those values, especially if my inherited class only has a couple of extra properties.

Reflection seems to hint at an answer.

I saw at [Using inheritance in constructor (publix X () : y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072249/using-inheritance-in-constructor-publix-x-y) that I can call the base class constructor (I think? correct me if I'm wrong), but my base class doesn't have a constructor - it's derived from the jira wsdl

```
        public remoteStatusCounts(RemoteStatus r) : base(r) { //do stuff }
```

---

**edit**
I can imagine 2 valid solutions: the one outlined above, and some sort of keyword like `this.baseClass` that is of `type(baseclass)` and manipulated as such, acting as a sort of pointer to `this`. So, `this.baseClass.name = "Johnny"` would be the exact same thing as `this.name = "Johnny"`

For all intents and purposes, let's assume the baseclass has a copy constructor - that is, this is valid code:

```
        public remoteStatusCounts(RemoteStatus r) {
            RemoteStatus mBase = r;
            //do work
        }
```

---

**edit2**
This question is more of a thought exercise than a practial one - for my purposes, I could've just as easily done this: (assuming my "baseclass" can make copies)

```
    public class remoteStatusCounts 
{
    public int statusCount;
    public RemoteStatus rStatus;
    public remoteStatusCounts(RemoteStatus r)
    {
        rStatus = r;
        statusCount = getStatusCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or code generation, but I'd rather not go that route.

Comment: Note: Your class names should start with a capital letter. `</code-format-nazi>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this - be aware though, that you might run into getter-only properties which you have to deal with seperately.

You can filter it with the `Type.GetProperties(BindingsFlags)` overload.

Note: You probably should look into code generation (T4 would be an idea, as it is delivered with vs 2008/2010), because reflection could have runtime-implications like execution speed. With codegeneration, you can easily handle this tedious work and still have the same runtime etc like typing it down manually.

Example:

```
//extension method somewhere
public static T Cast<T>(this object o)
{
    return (T)o;
}

public remoteStatusCounts(RemoteStatus r)
{
    Type typeR = r.GetType();
    Type typeThis = this.GetType();

    foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeR.GetProperties())
    {
        PropertyInfo thisProperty = typeThis.GetProperty(p.Name);

        MethodInfo castMethod = typeof(ExMethods).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(p.PropertyType);
        var castedObject = castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { p.GetValue(r, null) });
        thisProperty.SetValue(this, castedObject, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: How? I can't call setValue on objects.. this.setValue(p.Name,r.getValue) doesn't compile.

Comment: You of course have to get the Type object for this, get the corresponding property with t.GetProperty(name) and do the SetValue on that object.

Comment: It compiles like this:  thisProperty.SetValue(this, p.GetValue(typeR,null),null);


But then it throws a runtime exception "Object does not match target type"

Comment: Nope. Can't call getType() on static classes. +1 for getting closer.

Comment: Runtime exception - "TargetException was unhandled by user code - Object does not match target type." Thanks for working on this - I really don't know anything about reflection. I figured it should be possible, I really have no idea though.

Comment: fixed. tested it, this should work. the p.GetValue was wrong - It tried to get the value on the type object, which obviously will fail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198886/c-using-reflection-to-copy-base-class-properties - this question is similar.

Answer (score 2):

Try [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Home).

Comment: Sweet! I've never heard of that before - that will definitely come in handy sometime!