# Using C# 9 records "with" expression can I copy and add to new derived instance?

Tags: c#-9.0

Suppose I have the following:

```csharp
public record Settings 
{
  public int Setting1 { get; init; }
}

public record MoreSettings : Settings
{
  public string Setting2 { get; init; }
}
...

var settings = new Settings { Setting1 = 1 };

// This is an error - CS0117
MoreSettings moreSettings = settings with { Setting2 = "A string setting" };
```

Is there a clean way to achieve this?  Do I have the syntax wrong?
Obviously, in this contrived case I could just manually copy each base property.

```csharp
var moreSettings = new MoreSettings { Setting1 = settings.Setting1, Setting2 = "A String!" };
```

But what if the base record type has lots of properties?

Comment: This is not supported. In the case of a base record with lots of properties, you will have to copy them all, one by one. You might want to hop over to [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang) and make a suggestion, or look for an existing one, and cast your vote for it.

Comment: This isn't possible, and can't be in the general case - what if MoreSettings doesn't define a parameterless constructor for example?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I've been spending too much time in Typescript land.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From your original question,

```cs
MoreSettings moreSettings = settings with { Setting2 = "A string setting" };
```

`with` keyword internally ensures call to the copy constructor of the type, before changing the specified properties. The `Settings` record, in the example, does not have a property called Settings2, which is why this is not allowed.

Regarding your second approach, if the base class has a lot properties, you could introduce an additional constructor for the `MoreSettings` record, which accepts an instance of `Settings` as **workaround** for not having to add each of the properties as in the second example given in OP.

Instead, you could,

```cs
public record MoreSettings : Settings
{
   public MoreSettings(Settings parent) : base(parent) { }
   public string Setting2 { get; init; }
}
```

Now you could call make the call as

```cs
MoreSettings moreSettings = new MoreSettings(settings) { Setting2 = "A string setting" };
```

You could also remove the MoreSettings on right hand side by making use of Target-Type New expressions in C# 9

```cs
MoreSettings moreSettings = new (settings)  { Setting2 = "A string setting" };
```